# How do I Iterate Tree data?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a data structure like[image]

When I query this data base using

```
List<TextualReq> textualReqList = session.createQuery("from TextualReq where parent is null").list();
```

Here **TextualReq** Object is

```
  @Id
       @GeneratedValue( generator = "increment" )
       @GenericGenerator( name = "increment", strategy = "increment" )
       @Column(name="ID")
       private int                    id;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="parent")
       private TextualReq                parent;
       @OneToMany( mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
       @Column(name="children")
       private Set<TextualReq> children = new HashSet<TextualReq>();
       @Column(name="data")
       private String                  data;
```

I will get two records in "textualReqList". I needs to iterate and show this data something like 
[image]

Comment: I don't think that your query is right. First it does not have **select** in it. Second it will give only 2 records for which the parent is null

Comment: correct, It will give only two records, that are parents. when I pass the parent (NULL) to recursive function It will return child items.

Comment: @P.Jairaj For HQL you don't need to specify `select`.

Comment: @v.ladynev Oh. Okay did not know that. Thanks. But still it will return only 2 records!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it!

```
public void displayData(){
    display(null);
}
public void display(TextualReq textualReq){
    List<TextualReq> textualReqList = null;

    String parentId = "is null"; 
    if(textualReq!=null){
        parentId = "= "+textualReq.Id;
        System.out.println(textualReq.data);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    textualReqList = session.createQuery("select * from TextualReq where parent "+parentId).list();
    if(textualReqList==null)
        return;
    for(int i=0;i<textualReqList.size();i++){
        display(textualReqList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Just call the function **displayData()**.

Comment: Your query is correct only for `parentId` equals `null`. And It will be better to use a query parameter `:parentId`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding `toString()` method to TextualReq class:

```
public String toString() {
    return toStringWithPrefix("");
}

private String toStringWithPrefix(String prefix) {
    StringBuilder childrenAsString = new StringBuilder();
    for (TextualReq child : children) {
        childrenAsString.append(child.toStringWithPrefix(prefix + '\t'));
    }
    return String.format("%s%s%n%s", prefix, data, childrenAsString);
}
```

Then you can iterate over textualReqList and print every item:

```
for (TextualReq req : textualReqList) {
    System.out.print(req);
}
```